# Designing Integration Test Suite for Google Cloud Workflows, Dataflow & Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, integration-testing, google-cloud-pubsub, google-workflows

Need some advice on technologies and design choices for integration testing GCP Workflows which is triggered by Pub/Sub and starts the Dataflow job.

For running the tests locally, I was thinking of using Pub/Sub emulator but for workflows I would need to either trigger a test workflow execution or setup a workflow for testing purposes?

Any ideas on how to test such an environment or technologies that can be used to execute and assert test results will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since Workflows currently only runs in deployed environments, your best option is to deploy a test version, either to a test project or with a different workflow name than production.

If you want to test it directly, you can use `gcloud workflows run`, passing the same arguments as the Pub/Sub trigger, and check the result. Or you could configure the Pub/Sub trigger and send the message, then poll for the results using repeated `gcloud workflows executions describe` commands.